# What will be the actions taken over 'Unanswered' questions?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

I have seen there are a number of questions available who do not have a single answer; even though they are fully related to the 'Software Quality Assurance & Testing' on SQA-Beta site.

---

[image]

Most of the guys have been upvoted as a good question. I thought-If the questions have been asked by someone (new comers) & they don't have received a positive reply (answers) from our SQA experts; it may create negativity in their mind to come back next time.

To avoid this-What are the suggestions made to improve peoples mind to attract SQA site & get positive feedback from all of us and the newcomers will be happiest with the suggested answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be helpful for people to go through these questions and add answers if they can. I've done this periodically, where I know enough to answer the question.